# Newlines and contenteditable with nested non-editable tags

Tags: html, contenteditable

I have an odd case for `contenteditable` elements within HTML.  We have a rich text editor that customers load pre-made templates(by us) into, and then can modify that template however they want (mostly).

Parts of our templates have been marked to not be directly editable, but can still be removed, etc.  However, there seems to be an issue when one such element is the first element on a line (directly after a `<br/>` tag), and the user hits `DEL` on the line above.  Because its `contenteditable=false`, the browser seems to delete not the `<br/>` but the entire non-editable span.

Sample HTML is like this

```
<div contenteditable=true>
    <span>blah blah blah</span><br/>
    <span contenteditable="false">You cant edit this value directly</span>
</div>
```

If the user puts their cursor after the `blah blah blah`, and hits `DEL` the entire next content editable is deleted, rather than the line break.

Is there any way, javascript or otherwise, to fix this behavior?

Ive fooled around with attempting to detect the cursor position(using rangy), and inserting temporary spaces, etc, but I cant seem to get it to have the desired behavior, which is just that the non-editable tag gets brought up to the previous line.

We have limited the use of the editor to Chrome only, so no need to worry about IE or FF.

[jsfiddle of an example](http://jsfiddle.net/HgRsF/)

Comment: Is `<br/>` part of your template? If so could you not just use 3 `div`'s instead of using `<br/>`?

Comment: Yes.  For reasons I'm not entirely sure (probably for rendering), we have overridden the enter keypress to insert a line break instead of allowing the browser to insert, in this case, divs.

Comment: Another solution might be to take full control over the delete key events. You could use the inherited functionality when needed and block the event when not desirable. Or even use 100% custom delete logic. *Edit:* Admitted getting the caret position can be a little tricky, but it is certainly possible.

Comment: @LeaHayes yea, we've done something similar to that.  Its not perfect, but definitely better.   [rangy](http://code.google.com/p/rangy/) helped a lot in figuring out where the cursor was in the range

Comment: Aloha seems to have a fairly solid editor (that can be extended), perhaps worth a mention: aloha-editor.org

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make each span `contenteditable`, then the user won't be able to delete the span you don't want edited, and get rid of the div being editable.

Here's my version of the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/howderek/HgRsF/2/

Comment: This is a potential solution, but doesnt fit what we need, since this is within the scope of a rich text editor and the div is the block of editable area.  The spans inside the div are the result of a number of operations to style the text in a certain manner.

Comment: Ok. Can I ask why you want one span to be safe from editing even though it is within the editing area?

Comment: it was a bad design decision from the start, and unfortunately the product is far enough along that its stuck.  Those particular spans are reusable values, the content of which is managed differently, and can be plugged into several disparate documents.  They are ineditable from the content section so that the users are forced to use the reusable nature of them.  The real solution here was to manually handle the enter/delete key presses when we had to, and we have an okay solution to that, but still imperfect

Answer (score 0):

The question is from 2012, and since that time this problem was fixed and nested `contenteditable` tags work as intended. There are still some problems like [this bug](https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=238000), but in overall the feature should be usable.

Comment: This still seems to be showing up in the JSFiddle example linked to above on my browser (Chrome 40)